# How can i use locale with percentages?

Tags: javascript

I have this number `4030.146852312`

i need to get the four decimals from this percentage of this number so at the end i get

```
4030.1468
```

and transform this number according to locale

so for example

```
4.030,1468
```

how can I do this ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to round to at most 2 decimal places, if necessary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11832914/how-to-round-to-at-most-2-decimal-places-if-necessary) (The solutions there can easily be changed to 4 decimal places)

Comment: No, i need always four decimals

Comment: So, where exactly are you stuck? There are countless questions covering JS rounding, and a quick search for "JS convert number to locale string" brings up everything you should need for the formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easly use `Intl.NumberFormat` object:

```js
const number = 4030.1468;

console.log(new Intl.NumberFormat('de-DE', { minimumFractionDigits: 4, maximumFractionDigits: 4 }).format(number));
```

For more info https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat

Comment: What is minimumFractionDigits and maximum for ? Can you please explaing

Comment: @Code minimumFractionDigits and maximumFractionDigits are the minimum and maximum number of fraction digits to use, ranging from 0 to 20.